# How can read a read a .json local file within the application and pass the same to the page in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-select

I want to read a .json local file within the application and pass the same to the page when loading.

Below is my code

```
let HomePage = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
    return { jsonData: this.props.responseData };
},
componentDidMount: function () {

},

render: function () {
    return (
        <div className={"page " + this.props.position}>
           <div>{this.state.jsonData.name}</div>
        </div>
    );
}
});


let App = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function () {
},

componentDidMount: function () {

    var contentdata = fetch("js/myfile.json")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {

            this.setState({
                mydata: data
            });

            return data;
        })

    router.addRoute('', function () {
        this.slidePage(<HomePage responseData={this.state.mydata} />);
    }.bind(this));

}
});

React.render(<App />, document.body);
```

Here My HomePage rendered before the json file promise is resolved. So not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As you are not using ES6, you can use var data = require("js/myfile.json")
and then you can use the data to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- You should should just store it in a relative JS file
- You should abstract this call through an API

js/myfile.js

```
export const data = []
```

Create an API file in *utils/api.js*

```
import { data } from '../js/myfile.js'

export const fetchData = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(data)
  })
}
```

Component Snippet

```
import * as api from './utils/api'

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    api.fetchData().then(data => {
      this.setState({data})
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      // UI here
    }
  }
}
```